# Getting users friend data using FB Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

I am attempting to access a user's friends work and education history using the Graph API. I have included both permissions in the auth dialogue. I have tried accessing them using FQL but have had no luck.

```
try{
        $fql    =   "select friends_education_history from permissions where uid=" . $user;
        $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
        );
        $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        d($o);
    }
}
```

I'd prefer to access the info without using FQL but at this point, I need to figure out ANY way. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
 if($user_id) {
  try {
        $friends = $facebook->api("/me/friends");
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        d($o);
    }
}
?>
```

And then call the respective variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FQL query would look something like this:

```
SELECT education,work from user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Above query will fetch all education and work objects from friends of the logged in user.

```
SELECT education,work from user WHERE uid = <YOUR FRIENDS USER ID>
```

Above query will get education and work for just the one user id you provide

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Good to go now.

Comment: Matt, it would be great if you can mark it as the answer if it worked for you. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The [User graph api object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) has fields `education` and `work`.

Permissions `user_education_history` & `friends_education_history` are required for the first, `user_work_history` & `friends_work_history` for the second.

These fields are optional & a user can restrict their visibility via her profile page, so even having granted the permissions the api may return nothing.

Use the [Graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to have a play.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. I've requested the right permissions from the user, but the API doesn't return those fields if I switch from `/me/friends?fields=work,education` to `/#user_id#/friends?fields=work,education`.